# jqGrid multiple search dialog configuration

Tags: jquery-ui, search, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm facing an issue with jqgrid multiple search (php back-end). The search dialog does not show the "+" (add filter) unless I click on the Reset button...

This is the code:

```
jQuery("#poi_grid").jqGrid({ 
    url:'php/retrieve_pois.php', 
    datatype: "json", 
    colNames:['Name', 'Region', 'Type','Website','PDF','Lat','Lon'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:150}, 
        {name:'region',index:'region', width:70}, 
        {name:'type',index:'type', width:70}, 
        {name:'website',index:'website', width:90,sortable:false,search:false}, 
        {name:'pdf',index:'pdf', width:150,align:"right",sortable:false,search:false}, 
        {name:'lat',index:'lat', width:60, sortable:false,search:false}, 
        {name:'lon',index:'lon', width:60, sortable:false,search:false},
    ], 
    pager:'#pager',
    rowNum:20, 
    rowList:[20,30,50], 
    sortname: 'name', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "asc"
}); 
//Pager
jQuery("#poi_grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false}
)
//Custom buttons
.navButtonAdd('#pager',{
    caption:"",
    title:"Search", 
    buttonicon:"ui-icon search", 
    onClickButton: function(){ 
        jQuery("#poi_grid").jqGrid('searchGrid', 
            {sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn']},
            {multipleSearch:true}
        );
    }, 
    position:"last"
 });
```

This is what I get when I open the search dialog (searching works fine but I have no possibilities to add another filter):

When I click on the rest button in the lower left corner of the dialog (even without performing a search before) I see the "correct" structure of the dialog... and multiple filters search works:

How to solve and obtain the complete dialog without clicking on reset? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an error in the call of `searchGrid`. Instead of

```
jQuery("#poi_grid").jqGrid('searchGrid', 
       {sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn']},
       {multipleSearch:true}
);
```

you should use

```
jQuery("#poi_grid").jqGrid('searchGrid', 
       {sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn'], multipleSearch:true}
);
```

The problem which you describe with "Reset" button is just a bug in [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) of jqGrid (see more [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-in-the-single-search-dialog-box/#p23532)). Because of wrong usage of `searchGrid` the `multipleSearch:true` option will be ignored and the Searching dialog will be used as [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching).

Answer (score 2):

See this one.

```
jqGridObj = $('#poi_grid');

jqGridObj.navButtonAdd('#' + jqGridObj[0].id + '_toppager_left',{
    caption:"",
    title:"Search", 
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-search", 
    onClickButton: function(){ 
        jqGridObj.jqGrid('searchGrid', 
            {sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn'], multipleSearch:true, showQuery: true}
        );
    }, 
    position:"last"
 });
```